# loading an R environment (.RData file) in Windows

Tags: r, backslash, rdata

When I load an R environment (.RData file) in Windows, I always have to change the single slash("\") to double slashes("\") in path.

Is there an easier way to do this?

I tried replacing all "\" with "\", but that doesn't work either

```
load(gsub("\","\\","C:\Users\IAMTubby\Desktop\2015\Demo\Demo\Today.RData"))
```

Comment: Try `load("C:/Users/IAMTubby/Desktop/2015/Demo/Demo/Today.RData")`

Comment: @r3robertson, hmm that works. But is there a way I could modify \ itself, because, I usually copy the path from the file explorer on windows, which is in the "path\to\file" format

Comment: Try `gsub("\\", "/", ...)`

Comment: I work in windows as well. Because this situation rarely comes up for me, I typically just use ctrl + f and replace the "\"s with "/"s. Otherwise @Richard Scriven's answer should work.